# Find emails that haven't been replied with Python & Exchangelib

Tags: python, email, exchangelib

Currently I am using Python and Exchangelib module to build a macro that shows emails that haven't been replied.

Background for the macro:

A support group of 3 peoples get daily lot of emails from customers to "support@abc.com".
One of 3 peoples will reply back using the same email "support@abc.com" as sender.
Due to high amount of daily inbox and the fact that 3 peoples share the same email "support@abc.com" to respond, human error happens from time to time and therefore some emails stay unreplied.

What I would like to try is to use the following symbol as the sign if the email is replied.

[image]

**I could not figure out what the attribute for that is called.**

I have compared all attributes for the second and the third emails side by side. I was expecting that the second email has a certain boolean attribute X with value "True" while the third email "False" (or vice versa):
[image]
[image]

**Does such a boolean attribute exist?** If no, how could my web browser show the symbol on my first screenshot?

If it does not exist, how would you solve it?

Another alternative to solve it would involve any "support@abc.com"-reply would need to be sent not only to the customer but also to "support@abc.com" itself as CC or normal recipient.
After that I just need to read the attribute "conversation_id" and compare it to other earlier emails.
I don't like the alternative because of the CC, it would create a new element in "the solution" that is prone to human error.

Any inputs would be welcome.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any fields on the [Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/message-ex15websvcsotherref) object in EWS that tells you directly whether that message has a reply.

I think your best bet is to use the `conversation_id` of the message and check your Sent folder for that `conversation_id`. I believe that's what OWA does - messages where only one message is known with that conversation ID will not get the "replied" icon.

Comment: I was thinking about that as well. Nice attribute list btw. Thank you :-)